# Positive radial function with compactly supported Fourier transform

Tags: lie-groups, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a non-compact semisimple Lie group with finite center (for example $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$). Choose a maximal compact subgroup $K$. A bi-$K$-invariant function is called radial. Let $A$ be a maximal abelian subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$ with real dual $\mathfrak{a}^{\ast}$. For $r \in \mathfrak{a}^{\ast}$ denote by $\phi_r$ the spherical function associated to $r$. For a radial function $f$, we consider the spherical Fourier transform $$\hat{f}(r) = \int f(g) \phi_r(g)  dg.$$

My question is, if there exists a positive non-zero radial function on $G$ whose spherical Fourier transform is smooth and has compact support. This claim is easily established on $\mathbb{R}$ using that $\widehat{f^2} = \hat{f}*\hat{f}$. However I believe the latter identity does not hold for radial functions, but it holds that $\widehat{f_1 * f_2} = \widehat{f_1} * \widehat{f_2}$ for $f_1$ and $f_2$ radial. More precisely, I would like to find such a function $h$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) that is strictly larger than $1_{B(\varepsilon)}$, the characteristic function of the $\varepsilon$-ball around the identity, and that satisfies $||h||_1 \ll \mathrm{vol}_G((B(\varepsilon))$ uniformly in $\varepsilon$.